# Uniqueness of hash(time)

Tags: python, hash, architecture, md5, processor

I would like to create a unique identifier to a transaction.

Does the uniqueness of :

```
hashlib.md5( ( time.time() ).encode('utf-8') ).hexdigest()
```

depends on the architecture of the processor (multi-processing) ?

Comment: It's probably not even unique before hashing. Why involve time at all? What's wrong with a global counter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need a unique identifier, just go with [UUIDs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/uuid.html). Don't try to cook up your own UUID-equivalent using timestamps.

Answer (score 0):

Hashes can collide for different values of time. You will want to use a UUID -specifically UUID1 (there are several versions of UUID)

https://docs.python.org/2/library/uuid.html#uuid.uuid1

UUID1 uses time as an input, and so as long as the time at which the UUID is generated is different, you are guaranteed a different output.

Answer (score 0):

first of all hashing does not depend on architecture as hash algorithms are algorithms and by definition of algorithm they must be 'well defined' steps to achieve something, so no, architecture etc. won't have any effect.

secondly md5 is not safe as it is possible to have same md5 hash for different values in 'reasonable' time. [see wikipedia md5sum #security](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5#Security)